# Intel i7 4930K CPU box stock cooler dimensions

Tags: intel-core-i7, cpu-cooler

I'm not able to find the info about Intel's i7 4930K box stock cooler dimensions.

Intel homepage [mentions](http://ark.intel.com/products/77780/Intel-Core-i7-4930K-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz#@ordering) that this CPU can be bought in two flavors - boxed version (with cooler), and naked tray version. However, there is no info about the cooler's overall dimensions.

Anyone know them?

The reason for the question is that I'm not sure if stock cooler will fit in 3U rack case or not.

Basically, I'm interested in cooler height.

Comment: @Ramhound: Please define "3U cooler"

Comment: @Ramhound Where exactly have you found the information that "Intel Stock fan hasn't changed in years"? I doubt this is true due to different CPU sockets. I would appreciate if you could *prove* I'm wrong. Sure, I have a huge selection of fans out there, but I'm not willing to pay for it unless I have to.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks! I have found that stock cooler for socket 1155 is 50mm high: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/309472-28-dimensions-hard-find Please post your comments as an answer, and I'll approve it.

Comment: Wow. I've got a downvote for a perfectly valid question. O.o

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs You should really get a heatsink intended for use in a rack-mount case - please see the comment in the "possible duplicate" which Ramhound linked to.

Comment: @Ramhound Haha! Really? How do I know that? Please show me first where this is documented. I indicated that I was in doubt, and asked you to provide a proof. I never told you were wrong.

Comment: @Ramhound Also, I found it strange and wrong to make a downvote on the valid answer because of comments.

Comment: @Ramhound Looks like we both were wrong. There is no stock fan in i7!

Comment: Actually you're both right and wrong. The OP is talking about a LGA2011 model, which don't come with heatsinks. The 'mainstream' models do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, latest Intel i7 CPU's for LGA 2011 socket does not come with stock cooler anymore.

I hope this answer will help people decreasing delays in computer building by giving a hint that **you need to buy a cooler for latest LGA 2011 i7 models**.

[Reference](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1305373).

Comment: IIRC the EP models don't. The mainstream ones do